# Bound on $\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{[(zk+i)\delta ,(zk+i+1) \delta ]} \phi(x) dx - \frac1{k}$

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

I am trying to derive bounds on
$$S_i = \sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{[(zk+i)\delta ,(zk+i+1) \delta ]} \phi(x) dx,$$
where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $i=0,\dots,k-1$ and $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$. The function $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ stands for the density of normal rv.

I am particularly interested in how far $S_i$ from $\frac1{k}$ (i.e., a uniform distribution).

I could show $S_i\le \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{k}$ and is trying to derive a similar lower bound and improve my current upper bound. Thanks.

Comment: I see two ways you could try. 1) The value of phi is only really important near 0. Also, $\int_a^b \phi(x) \ge (b-a)*\phi(a)$ if $0 < a$ so you can approximate these integrals by function evaluations. 2) Alternatively, if you show that $|S_i-S_j|$ is small but $\sum S_i$ is large, then this implies that all of them have to be roughly equal to each other.

Comment: Thanks @SandeepSilwal. For 1), the bound you suggest worked well for the upper bound since I could further bound by changing the sum to integration. However, in the lower bound I do not know how to proceed from the sum. For your second suggestion, note that $\sum S_i = 1$, still trying to bound $|S_i-S_j|$ :)